# What S/L/l stands for in YYSTYPE/YYLTYPE/yylval/yylloc?

Tags: bison, flex-lexer

In flex/bison, there are two data types and corresponding static variables:

- YY**S**TYPE/yy**l**val
- YY**L**TYPE/yy**l**loc

I am wondering what `S/L/l` stands?

My guess is:

- `S` stands for `symbol` (i.e., symbol's semantic data types)
- `L` stands for `location`, and
- `l` stands for 'lexer' (meaning a variable to be shared with the lexer).

Comment: Why did you delete your question about wildcard symbols, out of curiosity?

Comment: I read the error recovery sections of the 'flex & bison' book, and realized that I can get my error reporting issue resolved. So I deleted my question :)

Comment: Btw, I put my simple calculator exercise on github: <https://github.com/xiongyw/myc>, in which I let the scanner only returns token type and the token text, and all the semantic interpretation of token text is handled by the parser. It's a kind of waste of memory and CPU cycles (a lot of extra `malloc()` and `free()`), but just for fun.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Questions of the form "why is this historical name spelled X?" are almost always unanswerable since it is hard to go back in time 30 or more years to find whoever first thought up the variable name and ask them what they were thinking about. Even if they are still alive, they might not now remember their original chain of thought.

It might be reasonable to ask a related question, "What mnemonic device can I use to keep these strange names straight in my head?" Of course, such a question would necessarily be culture-specific since a good mnemonic device for a first-language English speaker is not necessarily good for someone whose first language is Greek, for example. However, leaving that aside, here are my thoughts (with some small historic notes):

- `yylval` has been in Yacc since the beginning, as far as I know. Originally, it was paired with another externally-visible variable, `yyval`: `yylval` was the semantic value "returned" by the lexical scanner, and `yyval` was the semantic value generated by the production rule's semantic action (that is, what `$$` translated to). Thus, `yylval` is the (semantic value) of the lookahead token, and I'm pretty sure that's where the first `l` comes from. Even if it isn't the historical meaning, it's a reasonable mnemonic. (Unfortunately, the lexical type of the lookahead symbol is `yychar` rather than `yyltype`, so the mnemonic is not perfect.)
- I've always recommended thinking of `YYSTYPE` as meaning "**S**emantic **TYPE**", since the bison manual refers to "semantic values" produced by "semantic actions". I think the use of the adjective "semantic" here is also common in other literature. It's possible that the origin of the `S` came from "stack" (as in "the type of the value stack") but since the parser has several stacks, that's not a very useful mnemonic.
- Bison added location information to the parsing model, which meant that there needed to be another global variable with another datatype used to pass location information from the lexical scanner to the parser. It seems pretty clear that `YYLTYPE yylloc;` was produced by analogy with `yylval`, and indeed inside the bison-generated parser there is a local variable called `yyloc` which plays a role analogous to `yyval`. So the `L` in `YYLTYPE` can definitely be thought of as meaning "**L**ocation **TYPE**", while the first `l` in `yylloc` is similar to the first `l` in `yylval`, indicating the **loc**ation of the **l**ookahead token.

Comment: Great answer. For `S` stands for "Semantic", as I read the "C++ parser" section of "flex & bison" book today, it's clear that the book (`yy::cppcalc::semantic_type* yylval`) agrees with your suggestion . For 'l' stands for "lookahead", it's reasonable, and I think this is also a much better mnemonic device, as "lookahead" (of one token) is a vital part of LALR(1) parser. Many thanks!